# Can you please help me to resolve https://click.driverfortnigtly.ga/GMtCh34S malware problem?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, malware, malware-detection

My website **https://feminspacebeauty.com** is effected with a malware redirecting to ***https://click.driverfortnigtly.ga/GMtCh34S*** , I tried by asking help from hosting provider they send me a list of effected files details, I tried by removing those files but nothing happened, still the same ! anyone can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few tips which might help you....

1. Replace Core WordPress files
2. Regenerate .htaccess file
3. Update theme & plugins

Answer (score 0):

I know how you feel. My customer's site was just like your site.  my solution is always uninstalling website folders and database before set up backup. Note: Your back up files have to be clean. Can you check this website [WordPress Malware Redirect Hack  How To Detect & Fix It](https://secure.wphackedhelp.com/blog/wordpress-malware-redirect-hack-cleanup/).

Comment: Thanks bro. ! I think downloading all files and remove malware codes and upload it again without touching db ! may i know you there is any option to find the malware in a code by scanning code online ?

Comment: I guess it's to hard because already your website has a malware but you can scan the website. My prefer is iThemes Security for malware.

Comment: um using wordfence